# Is it possible to create a for loop inside an if condition?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

I need to check if some text areas are set, but there might be a lot of them. I want to check if every single one of them is set inside an if statement with a for loop.

```
if(//for loop here checking isset($_POST['item'.$i])  )
```

Comment: Your best approach would be to execute the loop before the if statement and assign a boolean with the result of the isset check. Then use the bool in your if statement

Comment: it's totally possible, give it a try

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Something that made you believe it's not possible?

Comment: You need to execute loop first and then check for the condition inside the loop, as simple as that

Comment: try your code in the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
// Assume all set
$allSet = true;
// Check however many you need
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    if (!isset($_POST['item'.$i])) {
        $allSet=false;   // If anything is not set, flag it and bail out.
        break;
    }
}

if ($allSet) {
  //do stuff
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

If you've only a few, or they're not sequential there's no need for a loop. You can just do:

```
if (isset($_POST['a'], $_POST['d'], $_POST['k']....)) {

// do stuff if everything is set

} else {
// do stuff if anything is not set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
$post=$_POST;
foreach($post as $key=>$value){
if (isset($value) && $value !="") {

// do stuff if everything is set

} else {
// do stuff if anything is not set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<?php
$isset = true;
$itemCount = 10;
for($i = 0; $i < $itemCount && $isset; $i++){
    $isset = isset($_POST['item'.$i]);
}

if ($isset){
    //All the items are set
} else {
    //Some items are not set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that after three answers, there isn't a correct one. It should be:

```
$success = true;
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
  if (!isset($_POST['item'.$i]))
  {
    $success = false;
    break;
  }
}
if ($success)
{
   ... do something ...
}
```

Many variation are possible, but you can really break after one positive.

Comment: Interesting that you should answer this now when there are already two almost identical answers here.

Comment: Sorry, no, they changed their answers... it happens, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one may have a loop within an if-condtional.  You may use a for-loop or you may find it more convenient to use a foreach-loop, as follows:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && $_POST != NULL ){

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        // perform validation of each item
  }
}
?>
```

The if conditional basically tests that a form was submitted.  It does not prevent an empty form from being submitted, which means that any required data must be checked to verify that the user provided the information.  Note that $key bears the name of each field as the loop iterates.